# iphone facebook login button not rendering

Tags: iphone, facebook, button, rendering

I'm using the [Facebook iPhone SDK](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk).

All I'm trying to do is display the login button given in the SDK though obviously I don't have a full understanding of views.

In my viewDidLoad method (i'm putting it here as I'm initialing the view with a nib) I have the following code:

```
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(30, 350, 90, 31);
  FBLoginButton* button = [[FBLoginButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
  [button setSession:delegate.session];
  [self.view addSubview:button];
  [button release];
```

The session that I'm passing in is valid but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used:

```
FBSession *session = [FBSession sessionForApplication:myApiKey secret:myAppSecret delegate:self];
[session resume];
[session retain];

FBLoginButton *fbLoginButton = [[FBLoginButton alloc] init];
[fbLoginButton sizeToFit];
fbLoginButton.center = CGPointMake(..., ...);
[self.view addSubview:fbLoginButton];
```

Comment: I've realize that the problem is with accessing the images in the FBConnect.bundle. I've moved the bundle to the resources folder but it still can't find them. 

To test this I just made a simple call as so

UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FBConnect.bundle/images/logout_down.png"];

I'm guessing there's a step I'm missing in Xcode that needs to be done when bringing the bundle into the resource folder? This is all new to me so I'm going to keep looking...

Comment: Figured it out. 

Went to Get Info for the bundle, then Targets and selected my App. 

thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

many things could be wrong here. if you are using NIBs have you correctly connected up the view in interface builder?

secondly, I don't know about the facebook sdk, but have you properly included the headers? I'm assuming you will need to include a class "FBLoginButton" somewhere. This may be as an @class in your .h file, or at the top of your .m file like `import "FBLoginButton.h"` (or similar).

Have you tried doing it all without setting the session. Also, have you tried creating a normal button (UIButton) instead of a FBLoginButton? Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, are you sure that you included the resource bundle as well ?

Its inside the framework, but in my experience, it doesn't get loaded correctly, unless you include it straight into your app as a resource. (You can still do it linked, so you don't have the same file twice)

Without the resouce bundle, the app has no graphics to design the button.